# PHP math question

Tags: php, math, format, rounding

Lets say I divide `14 / 15` times it by 100 to get the percentage which is `93.33333333333333` how can I display it as `93.3%` using php?

Here is the code.

```
$percent = ($avg / 15) * 100;
```

Answer (score 8):

The `sprintf` function is made for this (see also [the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php)):

```
echo sprintf('%.1f%%', $percent);
```

Comment: Depending on what you're looking for, round() ( http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php ) is also a good option.

Comment: echo sprintf() is an "antipattern". There is absolutely no reason that anyone should ever write echo sprintf() in any code for any reason -- it should be printf() every time.

Answer (score 8):

PHP has a [`number_format`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) function which lets you specify the number of decimals, what to use for the decimal separator, and what to use for the thousands separator:

```
$percent = ($avg / 15) * 100;
echo number_format($percent, 1) . '%'; // => 93.3%
```